# Getting position data from UBX protocol

Tags: python, gps, location

I am working on a project which is use **ublox** .ubx protocol to getting position information. I'm using serial communication to connect my GPS module and getting position information to python sketch. I used Serial and pyubx2 libraries my sketch as follows,

```
from serial import Serial
from pyubx2 import UBXReader

stream = Serial('COM8', 38400)
while True:
    ubr = UBXReader(stream)
    (raw_data, parsed_data) = ubr.read()
    print(parsed_data)
```

Then I have received information from GPS module as follows. It is continuously sending many of information in every second like as follows,

> <UBX(NAV-SOL, iTOW=00:11:43, fTOW=-215069, week=0, gpsFix=0, gpsfixOK=0, diffSoln=0, wknSet=0, towSet=0, ecefX=637813700, ecefY=0, ecefZ=0, pAcc=649523840, ecefVX=0, ecefVY=0, ecefVZ=0, sAcc=2000, pDOP=99.99, reserved1=2, numSV=0, reserved2=215800)>

> <UBX(NAV-PVT, iTOW=00:11:43, year=2015, month=10, day=18, hour=0, min=12, second=1, validDate=0, validTime=0, fullyResolved=0, validMag=0, tAcc=4294967295, nano=-215068, fixType=0, gnssFixOk=0, difSoln=0, psmState=0, headVehValid=0, carrSoln=0, confirmedAvai=0, confirmedDate=0, confirmedTime=0, numSV=0, lon=0.0, lat=0.0, height=0, hMSL=-17000, hAcc=4294967295, vAcc=3750027776, velN=0, velE=0, velD=0, gSpeed=0, headMot=0.0, sAcc=20000, headAcc=180.0, pDOP=99.99, invalidLlh=0, lastCorrectionAge=0, reserved0=2312952, headVeh=0.0, magDec=0.0, magAcc=0.0)>

I want to assign those position information (latitude, longitude, altitude etc.) into variables and hope to do some analysis part in further. So how can I derive positional information individually from this type of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (press CTRL-C to terminate) ...

```
from serial import Serial
from pyubx2 import UBXReader

try:
    stream = Serial('COM8', 38400)
    while True:
        ubr = UBXReader(stream)
        (raw_data, parsed_data) = ubr.read()
        # print(parsed_data)
        if parsed_data.identity == "NAV-PVT":
            lat, lon, alt = parsed_data.lat, parsed_data.lon, parsed_data.hMSL
            print(f"lat = {lat}, lon = {lon}, alt = {alt/1000} m")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Terminated by user")
```

For further assistance, refer to https://github.com/semuconsulting/pyubx2 (there are several example Python scripts in the /examples folder).